# Unity Dota style loading screen

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, loading, photon

I'm creating a 3v3 multiplayer game and I'm stuck on an important part before the gameplay comes in.
I was wondering how you would approach creating a Dota 2 style loading screen for loading characters into the game (Picture below).

Creating the UI isn't the problem. The problem is animating it to look clean while also having it actually load the game (terrain/gameobjects/etc) with a progress bar or something. 
I load the level with this

```
    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel('Game');
```

Then a gameobject spawns each player with

```
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate('....');
```

This works pretty well with nothing in the scene other than a plane to walk on. Now I just need to create the loading screen *BEFORE* the character loads while actually loading the terrain/objects/etc.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Dota 2 style loading screen example:
[image: IMG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a perfect case to use for [Scriptable Objects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects) in Unity.

Because as far as i remember there are around 100 heroes in Dota 2 and only 10 of them will be picked. So the images in this loading screen would change based on player input. Therefore, you should create scriptable objects. Then you can change the image(hero) also modify/add nick names to it in Run time. So to sum up you will have 10(in Dota but 6 is your case) scriptable object in your scene but you will only modify the images and nicknames after player selects the heroes.

Another benefit would be since they are objects you can easily animate them move up and down adjust however you want.

Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPXvoWVabPY) from Brackeys that is perfect for your case. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect answer!

Comment: As a gamer who played Dota for 9 years i am happy to help :)