# Different Sets of Scenes or Dynamically Changing UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine

After 4 years, I'm planning to return to Unity and a lot has changed. I'm planning a text based game, like choices games. But I'm not sure changing set of scenes by decisions or dynamically changing the GUI will be better and faster performance, easy to implement, and generic. Back then, I've used NGUI, unity's own GUI was really bad. So if you have a asset that helps this kind of things, I will also accept it as an answer. So, what do you guys think is the best approach?

Comment: I have not played choices games but from what i have seen from game play videos, I think you can take a look at this fresh [question]. Imo it can be applicable to your case and it will be generic. Performance would be much much better than changing sets of scenes as well.

Comment: @AliKanat your link for `question` is missing ;)

Comment: @derHugo Ah sorry :) Can't edit now so the question was this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55528517/unity-dota-style-loading-screen/55530853?noredirect=1#comment97767053_55530853)

Comment: @AliKanat Okay, but you may have misunderstood my problem. I mean this kind of text based choices game: https://youtu.be/7X0yjyi8oCs?t=651

Comment: Ah yeah i thought you would like to do a game like this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9c5XKqiBaA). In that case i don't see any other way of using dynamically changing UI to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'd like to make UI dynamic. It depends on the length of the game but I strongly believe you'd be using 100 scenes or something like that. Scene changes are okay but if user clicks fastly 6 times for a decision, it means 6 scene changes. And scenes would be stored as scenes which will make the app's size bigger compared to stored strings.

So yes, changing UI is better.